# Open source OMA DM Server besides Funambol

Tags: dm, oma

Are you aware of any open source implementations of an OMA DM Server besides Funambol or alternatively a library which implements OMA DM ?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to give a try to the [OMA-DM simulator](http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/simulators/omadm/) provided by Koneki (Eclipse open source project). The simulator uses its own library to implement the OMA-DM protocol. Feel free to use the [Koneki forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.koneki) to give feedback regarding the tool.

Comment: In my opinion the question is about an OMA DM server implementation other than Funambol. What Koneki provides is a simulator for testing the server.